# mysql database from excel table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import a usable mysql table into my database for an archery club. The idea is that you can work out an archer's handicap from this table by inputting just the scores and the type of round they have shot (which have names such as York etc..). The excel file is quite large and would be painful to input manually, so I have imported it as a csv file, all good. However I now need to work out a query to get the handicap I need and am not sure how to do this.

[image: excel sheet]

this is the excel table and below is the imported mysql table.

[image: phpmyadmin]

I will know what type of round has been shot and the score, I need to then lookup the nearest value on the line of columns horizontally adjacent to that type of round, and then in that column I need to return the handicap, which is the first line across the top? any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. This question is not about the excel at all. Right? Then reformulate it to the point you are asking.

Comment: The `COL #` is the number of round?

Comment: What SQL query do you use so far?

Comment: Learn about normalization to the 2nf. 
It is quite complicated if you're not used to it a first, but once you see "the light" it will serve you very well.

The columns you specified will be records in another table, probably something like "archery_club_id, handicap, value" and another table "id, archery_club_name" will suffice here. 

This is much more manageable than modifying columns all the time, just insert records into the "archeryclub_handicap_points" table.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking here (and it's a bad db design). Here's a guess if an archer in a hereford competition shoots a 10 then the handicap is 92?

Comment: thanks guys, I know the design of the database is bad, I am trying to find a way to design it that works and is simple. I will look at the normalisation suggestion , perhaps an example will explain more what I am looking for? Say you have an archer who shoots a Bristol III round of 290, his handicap will then be 89. Or if he shoots a Windsor round of 70, handicap will then be 84. I hope that makes more sense? I need to get the handicap from the round type and score?

Comment: P.Salmon that is correct